# SolrCloud setup error with collections API NPE

Tags: java, solr

I'm trying to set up a SolrCloud installation, and I have followed this guide: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloudTomcat

Browsing to any of the solr instances I receive this error message (as expected):

```
There are no SolrCores running.
Using the Solr Admin UI currently requires at least one SolrCore.
```

However, at the final step involving the curl command I get the following error:

```
curl 'http://mysolr1.com:8080/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=collection&numShards=4&replicationFactor=1'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
<lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">500</int><int name="QTime">11</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="trace">java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleResponse(CollectionsHandler.java:149)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleCreateAction(CollectionsHandler.java:277)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CollectionsHandler.handleRequestBody(CollectionsHandler.java:112)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:135)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.handleAdminRequest(SolrDispatchFilter.java:591)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:201)
    at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
</str><int name="code">500</int></lst>
</response>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It seems Solr unable to communicate OR Solr is not getting a expected response from ZooKeeper.

As per Solr 4.2.1 [Source Code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/tags/lucene_solr_4_2_1/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/handler/admin/CollectionsHandler.java):

```
Line 149 # QueueEvent event = coreContainer.getZkController()
.getOverseerCollectionQueue()
.offer(ZkStateReader.toJSON(m), DEFAULT_ZK_TIMEOUT);
```

So can you please verify:

Connect to ZooKeeper and verify Solr configuration presence ([may be this reference will help](http://myjeeva.com/solrcloud-cluster-single-collection-deployment.html#uploading-solrconfig-to-zookeeper))

Let me know the outcome!